# Exporting data sources between environments in pentaho

Tags: datasource, pentaho

I'm new with Pentaho and I'm trying to set up an automatic deployment process for the pentaho business analytics platform repository, but I'm having troubles to find out how to proceed with the data sources.

I would like to do export/import all the data sources, the same that [here](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.3/0P0/000/020) is explained with the repository (Reporting, Analyzer, Dashboards, Solution Files...) but with the data connections, mondrian files, schemas....

I know there's way to backup and restore the entire repository (explained [here](http://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.0/0P0/000/Backup_and_Restore_Pentaho_Repositories)), but that's not the way I want to proceed, since the entire repository could contain undesired changes for production.

This would need to be with command line or rest system or some other thing that be triggered by Jenkins.

Comment: Original question in forum pentaho See https://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?230305-Exporting-data-sources-between-environments

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `import-export` with the `-ds`(DataSource) qualifier ? This will include the data connection, mondrian schema and metadata models.

Otherwise, you can import everything, unzip, filter according a certain logic (to be defined by the guy in charge of the deployment), zip again and export it to prod. A half day project with the Pentaho Data Integrator.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I saw that parameter in the documentation but never saw an example on how to use it. This parameter expects an argument, but not sure what to add as parameter, how to identify an specific data source (I would like to import/export an entire Data Source Wizard) or how to tell pentaho to export all data sources (for this I see I can export everything and then remove all folders except for the "_datasources" folder, but I would like to see if there's a way to directly export/import this folder).

Comment: The argument is the name you gave to the datasource. But that is not what you are looking after. For some reason I cannot test on 7 write now, but if I do remember the import-export gives a xml which contains the data connections. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, the exportManifest.xml contains information about the metadata and mondrian files (schemas). I've tried doing a "import-export --backup" of everything, removing everything in the generated zip file except for the datasources folder and the exportManifest and then doing a "import-export --restore". This works fine but it will also update other things defined in the exportManifest such as user permisisons, passwords, etc... and I don't want to be updating this file manually to remove things, this process should be automated.

Comment: Yes, we stubbed on the same issue a year ago. User permission, password, acl, are NOT exported. I think it is on purpose. We ended up doing things manually, which was easy in our case. It maybe different in yours: What type of security provider are you using (Jackrabbit? Database?...). The security provider is the first line of the `security.properties` which is in the `pentaho-solution/system`.

Comment: What do you mean are not exported? In my case when I do a full backup and restore they are being exported. If I could somehow disable this, then I could work with this solution for the datasources. We are working with Jackrabbit by the way.
Thanks for your help by the way!